# How to implement Media Queries for android devices with small screens?

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, media-queries

I am working on a Phone gap project. I have implemented a swipe view feature. I have used an image for the background of the text. **The image size is around 304 * 250.**

It is working perfectly in screen size of 320 * 480 and screen size of 720 * 1280.

Now When I wanted to check the same in a screen size of 240 * 320 and screen size of 480 * 800? **Neither the background images were to be seen nor the data value.**

**Remedial step taken:**

I thought of using a box shadow instead of the image. I implemented it and tested it in screen size of 320 * 480.It was perfect.

I thought of testing the same in the screen size of 240 * 320 and screen size of 480 * 800 using **Media Query**

I referred from [here](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/) and I tried implementing it, But I was not successful.

My normal css

```
.container
{
    width:80%; height:auto; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; background-color:#CCCCCC; text-align:justify; border-radius:20px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; padding:10px; min-height:250px;
}
```

**My Media Query CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 240px) 
{
    .container
    {
       width:180px; height:150px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; background-color:#CCCCCC; border-radius:20px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; padding:10px; ;
    }
}
```

I have called the CSS in the following manner

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/common_set.css" />
```

**Problem:**
It did not get implemented.I could not see the box.It was just an empty screen.

Is there any mistake in my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you did it in your app, but here you have two semi-colon at the end of your CSS code

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 240px) 
{
   .container
   {
      width:180px; height:150px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; background-color:#CCCCCC; border-radius:20px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888; padding:10px; **;**
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah,I did that mistake in my Application. But,even after rectifying it. No change in the output view

Comment: any other suggestions...please

Comment: Try with a larger max-device-width, e.g. max-device-width: 300px

Comment: Cana sir,any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

First of all add this meta tag at your html file.

```
<meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
```